# How do I take a comment thread elsewhere?

Tags: support, comments, chat

A wrote a comment on [an answer](https://serverfault.com/a/672403/214507). That turned into a discussion, which I now feel is off-topic for the original answer. I'm thinking the right thing to do is to take the discussion to chat, before I write another reply.

In the past I have seen a button to perform this automatically, but I cannot find the button on this particular comment thread. Is there another way I can achieve the same that this button would have done, if it had been there?

Answer (score 7):

The "take this discussion to chat" button appears automatically if the thread is long enough, but I don't see a way for either users or moderators to force this to happen for shorter discussions.

Cheap workaround: Maybe just add a few bogus comments.

Comment: FYI (mod-only link, use TL for any discussion): http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19983268#19983268

Comment: `Cheap workaround: Maybe just add a few bogus comments.` - Or just create a room and post the link?